# Adding methods to existing class - inheritance/injection

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns

I have a dozen service classes that were built for WCF, e.g.:

```
 public class BookingService : IBookingService
 {
        public void BookTheThing(int ThingID) { .. }
 }
```

We are aiming to reuse these classes as direct libraries (not WCF) and create a separate service library which would allow us preserve and expose those existing methods and add new ones. Here are 2 possibilities I've come up with based on my limited experience:

*Option#1 - Inject original class and create identical methods to expose it's functionality:

```
public class BookingServiceNew : IBookingServiceNew
{
    public BookingServiceNew(IBookingService service) { _baseService = service; } 
    public void BookTheThing(int ThingId) { _baseService.BookTheThing(ThingId); }

    public bool OurNewMethod1(int ThingId) { return true; }
    public int OurNewMethod2(int ThingId) { return 1; }

}
```

*Option#2 - Inherit original service class, which would automatically expose its methods as part of the class, and then add our own stuff

```
public class BookingServiceNew : BookingService, IBookingServiceNew
{
    public bool OurNewMethod1(int ThingId) { return true; }
    public int OurNewMethod2(int ThingId) { return 1; }
}
```

Option#1 seems like it will have some more code and duplication having to create a stub for every method in the implentation and interface. Option#2 seems like it could have some issues with dependency injection on the client, where working against IBookingServiceNew would only provide access to OurNewMethod1 & OurNewMethod2.
Again, these options I've come with are based on my very limited experience and I would appreciate your thoughts and suggestions on a better approach/practice/pattern to follow.

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind commenting on why "working against `IBookingServiceNew` would only provide access to `OurNewMethod1` ..." ? (assuming `interface IBookingServiceNew : IBookingService`)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend going with option 1 (composition) over inheritance. Yes, this requires additional boilerplate code to expose each method of the inner service. However, this code has no logic so we're not really "repeating" anything. Furthermore, by using composition you gain a ton of flexibility down the line; if you decide you don't want to expose the same interface in IBookingServiceNew as in IBookingService you can simply remove/change those methods without modifying the original BookingService implementation. You can also easily swap in a new implementation of IBookingService (e. g. a mock in a unit test).

In contrast, using class inheritance to avoid the boilerplate saves some code in the short run, at a big cost to flexibility and maintenance. For one, you give up the ability to extend a different base class in the future. Now, your BookingService class must be designed for inheritance; you'll have to be careful about which internal methods and state are exposed to the subclass, and you need to worry about introducing conflicts with methods in the derived class. In general, the API exposed by a class which you expect to be extended is much more complex and harder for the consumer to understand than the one exposed by an interface. As a general rule, I try to avoid using class inheritance unless I will actually be making use of polymorphism (as opposed to just including methods from the base class). In this case, you're already using interfaces, so you have no need for the class polymorphism.

Finally, note that your concern about IBookingServiceNew not exposing the methods on IBookingService is easily addressed by either (1) putting those methods on IBookingServiceNew as well or (2) having IBookingServiceNew extend IBookingService.

Comment: Isn't it called composition? And Composition over Inheritance?

Comment: @Fendy: not sure what I was thinking. I've changed it.

Answer (score 0):

What about [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)?

```
public static class BookingServiceExtensions
{
   public static bool OurNewMethod1(this IBookingService service, int ThingId)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```